# my agora npm start does not installed Downloading frontend and installing dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, agora.io

**This give me this erroes pleasee help me**

when i type in terminal npm start my terminal installed all things but downloading frontend and installing dependencies this give me error

```
Error: spawn npx ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)        
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\agora-app-builder\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)        
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npx',
  path: 'npx',
  spawnargs: [
    'react-native',
    'init',
    'ConfrencecallingappKeshav',
    '--title',
    '"Confrence Video Calling"',
    '--template',
    'agora-appbuilder-core@1.0.8'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
npm ERR! agora-app-builder@1.0.0 start: `agora-app-builder-cli`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the agora-app-builder@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pawan gupta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-07T07_10_57_699Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What's your PATH?

Comment: C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\agora-app-builder

Comment: The issue could be because of the spaces in the folder names. Please paste the content of the log file mentioned as well. Most likely the answer is there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you execute `npm i` before `npm start`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a no directory error, clean the node_modules folder and execute `npm i` in your project directory then execute `npm start`.